# Connected function runs twice and exits

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I'm frustrated when trying to figure out how to connect correctly editingFinished with a function.

Couldn't make the code shorter, because every time I did, it worked, but I need the other parts.
Anyone has a clue?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(991, 695)
        self.gridLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(Dialog)
        self.gridLayout_4.setObjectName("gridLayout_4")
        self.buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(Dialog)
        self.buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        self.buttonBox.setObjectName("buttonBox")
        self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.buttonBox, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(Dialog)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.regular_file1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.regular_file1.setObjectName("regular_file1")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.regular_file1)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_3")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.regular_file1)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.regular_file1)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.label)
        self.gridLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_3, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.verticalScrollBar_2 = QtWidgets.QScrollBar(self.regular_file1)
        self.verticalScrollBar_2.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.verticalScrollBar_2.setObjectName("verticalScrollBar_2")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.verticalScrollBar_2, 3, 1, 1, 1)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.regular_file1)
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.listWidget)
        self.verticalScrollBar = QtWidgets.QScrollBar(self.regular_file1)
        self.verticalScrollBar.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.verticalScrollBar.setObjectName("verticalScrollBar")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.verticalScrollBar)
        self.listView = QtWidgets.QListView(self.regular_file1)
        self.listView.setObjectName("listView")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.listView)
        self.gridLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.regular_file1)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_4.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_4.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.pushButton_4.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(34, 16))
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_4)
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.regular_file1)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_5.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_5.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.pushButton_5.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(34, 16))
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_5)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(388, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.regular_file1)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_3.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_3.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.pushButton_3.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(34, 16))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
        self.gridLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2, 4, 0, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.regular_file1)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")

        #### IMPORTANT PART ####
        a = "MY NAME"
        self.lineEdit.editingFinished.connect(lambda x=a: self.search(x))


        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.regular_file1, "")
        self.yaml_file2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.yaml_file2.setObjectName("yaml_file2")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.yaml_file2)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.gridLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout_5.setObjectName("gridLayout_5")
        self.tabWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.yaml_file2)
        self.tabWidget_2.setObjectName("tabWidget_2")
        self.only_ref_tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.only_ref_tab.setObjectName("only_ref_tab")
        self.horizontalLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.only_ref_tab)
        self.horizontalLayout_6.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_6")
        self.listWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.only_ref_tab)
        self.listWidget_2.setObjectName("listWidget_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_6.addWidget(self.listWidget_2)
        self.tabWidget_2.addTab(self.only_ref_tab, "")
        self.only_dev_tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.only_dev_tab.setObjectName("only_dev_tab")
        self.horizontalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.only_dev_tab)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_5")
        self.listWidget_3 = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.only_dev_tab)
        self.listWidget_3.setObjectName("listWidget_3")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.listWidget_3)
        self.tabWidget_2.addTab(self.only_dev_tab, "")
        self.modified_tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.modified_tab.setObjectName("modified_tab")
        self.gridLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.modified_tab)
        self.gridLayout_3.setObjectName("gridLayout_3")
        self.listWidget_4 = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.modified_tab)
        self.listWidget_4.setObjectName("listWidget_4")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.listWidget_4, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.tabWidget_2.addTab(self.modified_tab, "")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.tabWidget_2, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.horizontalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_4")
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(388, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addItem(spacerItem1)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.yaml_file2)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.pushButton_2.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(34, 16))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        self.gridLayout_5.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_4, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.gridLayout_5, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.yaml_file2, "")
        self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.tabWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.tabWidget_2.setCurrentIndex(2)
        self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(Dialog.accept) # type: ignore
        self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(Dialog.reject) # type: ignore
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "TextLabel"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "TextLabel"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("Dialog", "next diff"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("Dialog", "prev diff"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Open with editor"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.regular_file1), _translate("Dialog", "regular_file"))
        self.tabWidget_2.setTabText(self.tabWidget_2.indexOf(self.only_ref_tab), _translate("Dialog", "only_ref"))
        self.tabWidget_2.setTabText(self.tabWidget_2.indexOf(self.only_dev_tab), _translate("Dialog", "only_dev"))
        self.tabWidget_2.setTabText(self.tabWidget_2.indexOf(self.modified_tab), _translate("Dialog", "Modified"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Open with editor"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.yaml_file2), _translate("Dialog", "yaml_file"))


    ### IMPORTANT PART ###
    def search(self, a):
        print(f"hello world {a}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Desired output:

```
hello world MY_NAME
```

The REAL output:

```
hello world MY NAME
hello world MY NAME
```

and the program crashes with no explanation of the problem...

Any ideas?

*** EDIT ***
The trigger is when editing the line and pressing "Enter".

When commenting out these lines:

```
self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(Dialog.accept) # type: ignore
self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(Dialog.reject) # type: ignore
```

It works... I don't understand... :(

#### SOLUTION

I have no idea why anyone would think that this question is duplicated... it has nothing to do with the link attached to it.

So for anyone else who would arrive here:
The answer is that when I pressed Enter, the OK button was triggered as well. You could see a blue mark surrounding it, that means that when you press the Enter, then he thinks that he's been pressed as well and that explains why the program exits.
That explains why when I commented out the "okButton.connected", it worked.
Solution is for me to put a new button that would act like an Enter button, but you could disable the OK button as well.

Comment: How are you triggering the editing finished?

Comment: Pressing "Enter" on the line

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#editingFinished) is clear:

> void QLineEdit::editingFinished()
>
> This signal is emitted when **the Return or Enter key is pressed** or **the
> line edit loses focus**. Note that if there is a validator() or
> inputMask() set on the line edit and enter/return is pressed, the
> editingFinished() signal will only be emitted if the input follows the
> inputMask() and the validator() returns QValidator::Acceptable.

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

In your case the following happens:

- When you press enter the signal editingFinished is emitted.
- As it is an enter, the accepted signal of the QDialog is also activated, which closes the window and that makes the QLinEdit lose focus, so the editingFinished signal is emitted again.

You have several options:

- Don't use QDialog but a simple QWidget if you can.
- Print if the QLineEdit has the focus: `if self.lineEdit.hasFocus():` `print(f"hello world {a}")`.

Note: The program does not break but a QDialog has the default behavior when enter is pressed.

Comment: It doesn't explain why does the EDIT work...
It has the same QDialog.
and the if statement inside the "search" function didn't work...

Comment: @urie I already pointed that out in:  *As it is an enter, the accepted signal of the QDialog is also activated, ...*.  You have removed the connection so accept is not called so the window does not close and therefore QLineEdit has not lost focus.